# Cannot enlist Synchronization. LocalTransactionCoordinator is completing or completed issue with hibernate spring transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, websphere

I am getting Cannot enlist Synchronization. LocalTransactionCoordinator is completing or completed exception when integrating my method is called from the portlet.

I am using spring transaction management for handling all the hibernate transaction in the spring configuration file through AOP.

When I run my hibernate dao method for persisting the data through Junit its working fine.

**Exception description:**

I am facing an issue that is when I run my code through unit test case  data is getting updated in database  properly  but when I run the  same code with integration with portlet  my code is executing finely but after the completion of transaction the records is not getting updated to database. The following error can be seen in the log which is

```
[4/7/10 23:06:38:685 MDT] 0000006c LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0014E: Cannot enlist Synchronization. LocalTransactionContainment is completing or completed.
[4/7/10 23:06:38:689 MDT] 0000006c LocalTransact E   J2CA0026E: Method addSync caught java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enlist Synchronization. LocalTransactionCoordinator is completing or completed.
      at com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl.enlistSynchronization(LocalTranCoordImpl.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.addSync(LocalTransactionWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.initializeForUOW(ConnectionManager.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.involveMCInTran(ConnectionManager.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.associateConnection(ConnectionManager.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.associateConnection(ConnectionManager.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.reactivate(WSJdbcConnection.java(Compiled Code))
      at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.getWarnings(WSJdbcConnection.java:1539)
```

Comment: Please help in resolving this issue.

Expert voice help need

Comment: Can you provide a more complete stack? The product does not allow transaction enlistment from certain callbacks, but it's not clear why this code flow is happening in the first place.